# Use another monospaced font

Tags: fonts

I want to use a different monospaced font for `\texttt`. I'm particularly fond of Bitstream Vera Sans Mono. If possible, not with XeTeX, since I'm not yet really familiar with it. Solutions using XeTeX would still be welcome, of course.

I hope this doesn't violate the one-question policy:

1. How do I change the monospaced fonts invoked by `\texttt{foo bar baz...}`?
2. Where can I find a list of other fonts that I can use without invoking XeTeX?

Comment: Since the question is explicitly *not* about xetex, I removed the `xetex` tag. Also it was decided that the `latex` tag should not be used.

Comment: A nice sans serif monospace font is [Source Code Pro](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Code+Pro) from Google. You can us it just by importing it:
`\usepackage{sourcecodepro}` See also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572171/213).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

for font support out of the box with your tex distribution, check out https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/

for monospaced, inconsolata is quite nice i think.

install the package, then load it up:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
```

A working example looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\begin{document}

this is a \texttt{mono spaced font example}.

\end{document}
```

bera mono is somewhat close to bitstream mono. load it up like this:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
```

for xetex or xelatex, you need the fontspec package, and the font installed to your system, then load the font with fontspec:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Courier New}
```

A working example in xelatex looks like this:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final,openright,twoside]{memoir}
\RequireXeTeX %Force XeTeX check

%XeLaTeX packages
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec} %Font package
\usepackage{xunicode}


%Select fonts
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont{Bitstream Vera Mono}

\begin{document}

\textrm{Ya! System} \texttt{fonts are} \textsf{so nice!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps an example with \setmonofont would make more sense given the question?

Comment: Bera Mono *is* Bitstream Vera Mono, isn't it? I thought "Bera" was just a contraction of Bistream Vera.

Comment: Added some more examples, and one with \setmonofont like Will suggested. Bera and Bitstream might be the same thing. I wasn't sure, and I'm still not :P