# Which fonts are at my disposal with pdfLaTeX without having to resort to manual installation of them?

Tags: fonts

Apparently, installing fonts manually (by converting them to `fd` files and so on) on LaTeX is a bit of a hassle. But still, I would like to be able to use fonts other than the standard Computer Modern (although it is a nice font).

So what fonts can I use without having to install them manually? By this I mean, which fonts are installed by standard, and which fonts can I access by including a package?

Comment: Related question: [Use another monospaced font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5443/791). Chosen answer there is to see [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [Which LaTeX fonts can be practically considered as available on most platforms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2814/which-latex-fonts-can-be-practically-considered-as-available-on-most-platforms)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look on the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) and also the [fonts directory on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/) for a list of available fonts.
Many of them can be loaded like packages. I only have experience with `cm-super` and `lmodern`.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

1. You can use every font you want if you change the engine to xelatex. With fontspec you can easily use every font installed in your system.
2. There are scripts like [installfont](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/installfont.html) that will create the support files for your fonts if you want to stay with (pdf)latex.
3. The fonts section in the [TeX catalogue by topic](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html#fonts) might be a good starting point what fonts are already available in your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not really familar with the font handling for `pdftex` it is absolutely no fun to build the files for `pdftex` support. However, a list of available fonts with an existing LaTeX support is the one from [Stephan Hennig](http://home.arcor.de/stephanhennig/Downloads/de_fc.zip), which is only available in german.

Comment: This link is unfortunately dead.