# How to get a monospaced sans-serif font for the source code when using lstinputlisting

Tags: fonts, listings

I have a document similar to this:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Matlab,%
  basicstyle=...
}

\subsection*{Matlab code}
\lstinputlisting{../myScript.m}

\end{document}
```

I have found several answers on how to use `lstlisting` with a monospaced font and a few on how to get a sans-serif font by setting `basicstyle` equal to `\ttfamily` or `\sffamily` respectively.

But what should I do if I like to display my source code in a monospaced AND sans-serif font?

Comment: You need a font that matches your criteria. With Xe-/LuaLaTeX this would be easy (something like Fira Mono).

Comment: Please provide compilable code, as this is much more helpful than mere fragments. In this case, however, the issue is to find a font to your liking, as @TeXnician says.

Comment: @cfr Since I am using `\lstinputlisting{...}` I think what is contained in my question is about the best "MWE" (or rather "ME") I can come up with as I shouldn't provide the rather text heavy input file.

Besides it doesn't really matter what the input file is, so just write something in `sometext.txt` and save it in the same folder as the TeX-file and replace `../myScript.m` with `sometext.txt`.

The reason I provide `basicstyle` with no value is because I hoped that someone would fill it out solving my problem. However the answer doesn't seem that simple for pdfLaTeX...

Comment: @TeXnician I must admit that I am not familiar with Xe- or LuaLaTeX, but can you write an example with XeLaTeX? I did try to configure TexMaker to XeLaTeX and that adding `\usepackage{fontspec}` followed by `\setmonofont{...}` to the preamble, but I hadn't luck in finding any font package names of the fonts in my system that are both monospaced AND sans-serif...but maybe I have got the approach all wrong?

Comment: Exactly: it doesn't matter. So don't provide the 'text heavy' input file. Just 'write something in `sometext.txt`' and copy it into your question for people to copy-paste. You can use `filecontents` to make this more convenient, though people will deal with it if you don't. People are more likely to provide you with an example solution if all they have to do is add the font stuff to what you give them. They are less likely to if they have to complete your fragment first. You need a document class, too.

Comment: Your approach with setmonofont seems right. If you've installed a complete TeX distribution you can use "Fira Mono" as argument. Then use `basicstyle=\ttfamily` and you're done.

Comment: @cfr I'll take notice of that.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks a lot. The "Fira Mono" didn't work, but the problem was as you suggest to find a proper font stored in my system. It work with the font "Noto Sans".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have access to fonts provided by your operating system, achieving your goal is straightforward: (a) Employ LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX) instead of pdfLaTeX; (b) load the `fontspec` package and load a suitable monospaced font via a `\setmonofont` directive; and (c) after loading the `listings` package, add the option `basicstyle=\ttfamily` to the argument(s) of `\lstset`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{...} % select a suitable main text font
%\setsansfont{...} % select a sans-serif font
\setmonofont{Lucida Console}[Scale=MatchLowercase] % select a suitable monospaced font

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
Hello World. \lstinline{Hello World.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice sans serif monospace font is [Source Code Pro](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Code+Pro) from Google. You can use it just by importing it:

```latex
\usepackage{sourcecodepro}
```

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sourcecodepro}

\begin{document}
\texttt{This text is in source code pro.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Source code pro]